# Applying patch folder to a linux kernel

Tags: patch, command-line-interface

I have folder of patches(patchfile1.patch,patchfile2.patch and patchfile3.patch).How can I patch linux kernel from the patches given in this folder via single command.Or do i have to apply the patch one at a time from the folder

```
cd /kernel-directory 
patch -p1 < patchfile1.patch
patch -p1 < patchfile2.patch
patch -p1 < patchfile3.patch
```

etc

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about patching a Linux system. You'd probably do better asking on [unix.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: no offense , but why Linux and Unix tag exists on SO?

Comment: They exist for people _developing_ software specifically for those environments - device drivers, kernel patches etc. Yours is not a development question.

Comment: @MikeW `patch` is one of the [software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it would be possible to concatenate all the patch fiels and apply them at once.
However, you should apply them one at a time so that it is possible to detect which one, if any, has an error or is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply them all in a loop:

`` $ for p in `ls -v /path/to/patches/*.patch`; do patch -p1 < $p; done ``

Note that for many patch sets, the order in which they're applied matters. I used the `-v` switch to GNU `ls` above to get the natural sort. Otherwise, once you hit patchfile10.patch, the order from `ls` would look like:

```
patchfile1.patch
patchfile10.patch
patchfile2.patch
...
```

Which may be fine, but not always.